# How to make a mailto html tag with html body in it The content

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to make a mailto html tag with html body in it. The content I want to send is

> Hello "Name"
>
> Good Morning (in bold)

How can I make this possible ?

I tried to put `<br/> <b>` etc in mailto body attribute but not worked.

My body content is generated using c# code

**code behind**

```
mailLink.InnerHtml = string.Format("<a href=\"mailto:help@domain.com?Subject=Help code&body='" + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result.ToString()) + "'+\"target=\"_top\">Send Mail</a>");
```

**aspx page**

```
<div id="mailLink" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto). It should help

Comment: you cant use html tags (bold) in body of mailto

Answer (score 0):

As answered here: [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

The standard for the mailto HTML tag to have the body was designed for a small plain text message only.

What would be better is to have the link activate an API or process that sent your message instead. And that could be a URL link. Like this answer:
[how to send email through asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386183/how-to-send-email-through-asp-net-web-api)

Let us know what you did to work around the issue.